# iText7 Image Quality Optimizer not working as document

Tags: c#, itext, pdf-generation, itext7, image-compression

I am using `iText7`'s `PDF Optimizer` product. It is very simple to use, but it is not reducing the image quality and size of my PDF at all. I'm using exactly same code as given in their product's live [LIVE DEMO](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/pdf-optimizer), but it is not working as documented. I'm using it's `C#` version.
I tried toggling *image_scalar_level* and *compression_level* as given in code, but it did not make any impact. If I upload same PDF file for testing their demo, it works fine.
What am I doing wrong? Any help/guidelines would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** *(adding code that I'm using, as request)*

```
        LicenseKey.LoadLicenseFile("license-key-path.xml");

        PdfOptimizer optimizer = new PdfOptimizer();

        /* Here we instantiate a FileReportBuilder which we can use as a log of the efficacy of
            our optimization.  Security level configuration possible.                          */

        FileReportPublisher publisher = new FileReportPublisher(new FileInfo("report.txt"));
        FileReportBuilder builder = new FileReportBuilder(SeverityLevel.INFO, publisher);
        optimizer.SetReportBuilder(builder);

        optimizer.AddOptimizationHandler(new FontDuplicationOptimizer());
        optimizer.AddOptimizationHandler(new FontSubsettingOptimizer());

        /* Scales down and compresses Image objects. In this case, we scale and compress a
             Tiff image by 50% */
        ImageQualityOptimizer tiff_optimizer = new ImageQualityOptimizer();
        tiff_optimizer.SetTiffProcessor(new BitmapCompressor(.05f, .05f));
        optimizer.AddOptimizationHandler(new ImageQualityOptimizer());
        optimizer.AddOptimizationHandler(new CompressionOptimizer());

        ColorSpaceConverter RGB_to_CMYK_Converter = new ColorSpaceConverter();
        CsConverterProperties csConversionProperties = new CsConverterProperties(ColorConversionMode.NORMAL);
        RGB_to_CMYK_Converter.SetCsConverter(new RgbToCmykCsConverter(csConversionProperties));
        optimizer.AddOptimizationHandler(RGB_to_CMYK_Converter);

        // Document is optimized according to defined handlers and written out to file.
        optimizer.Optimize(
                new FileInfo(@"D:\sample-input\ImageQuality_Optimization_Input.pdf"),
                new FileInfo(@"D:\sample-input\ImageQuality_Optimization_Input_OPT.pdf"));
```

Following is the content of `report.txt` after code executes:

```
[INFO] PdfOptimizer/FontDuplicationOptimizer: No font duplication found
[INFO] PdfOptimizer/FontSubsettingOptimizer: Glyphs in document were found successfully.
[INFO] PdfOptimizer/ColorSpaceConverter: Color space of the content stream with reference 5 0 R was converted.
[INFO] PdfOptimizer/ColorSpaceConverter: Color space of the content stream resources was converted.
```

The pdf file that I'm using is the from their Image Quality Compressor Demo at their KB article [HERE](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/files/44794752/44795978/1/1618393337000/ImageQuality_Optimization_Input.pdf).
Link to the KB article is [HERE](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/pdfoptimizer-support-added-for-font-image-color-space-optimization)

Comment: can you share the code you are using? Are you trying the Sandbox, or the "app" on the "[LIVE DEMO](https://itextpdf.com/en/demos/pdf-optimizer)"?

Comment: @AndréLemos I have added the code I'm using. It's almost copy-paste of the demo version. I have also included the `result.txt` file that is generated against the execution. There is no effect on file at all. It remains same size. Whereas in their KB articles, it reduces ALOT.

Comment: @AndréLemos I'm trying the upload on left on their LIVE DEMO.

Comment: I think you're on to something here. It works with Java, but there's some oddity in .NET. We will investigate this.

Comment: can you try adding System.Drawing.Common Version="4.7.0" as a dependency?

Comment: @AndréLemos I have tried adding System.Drawing.Common Version="4.7.0", but it did not make any difference. I also tried updating it to latest version but it also did not work. Thank you for your support

Comment: Hi!
First of all in the example of code, which you added, you don't add `tiff_optimizer` as optimization handler. And in `report.txt` there is no logging from `ImageQualityOptimizer`. It means that there was no image quality optimization.

But as i understand, if you add `tiff_optimizer` you will see the follow line in `report.txt`: `[ERROR] PdfOptimizer/ImageQualityOptimizer: Unable to optimize image with reference 7 0 R of type TIFF`, yes?

Comment: @DmitryChubrick you are right. I created the `tiff_optimizer`, but did not add it as optimzation handler. After adding `optimizer.AddOptimizationHandler(tiff_optimizer);` the the image was optimized. Please add it as an answer, so that I can accept it.

Comment: @AndréLemos adding `System.Drawing.Common Version="4.7.0"` is also the part of the solution. Please add this as your answer, so that I can comment and vote.

Comment: I'll let Dmitry get all of the Internet points!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In your example, you don't add `tiff_optimizer` as an optimization handler. And in `report.txt` there is no logging from `ImageQualityOptimizer`. That means, that there was no image quality optimization. But as I understand, if you add `tiff_optimizer` you will see the following line in `report.txt`:

   ```
   [ERROR] PdfOptimizer/ImageQualityOptimizer: Unable to optimize image with reference 7 0 R of type TIFF
   ```
2. `PdfOptimizer` doesn't throw any exception, if during the optimization any exception is thrown, current handler from handlers chain is finished and writes log that it is unable to do the specified action.
3. To understand source of problem I debugged the method `PdfOptimizer#Optimize` and found out that the exception is thrown in `ImageQualityOptimizer#optimizePdf`

   ```
   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   ```

   and `ImageQualityOptimizer` catches it and writees the log.

**So to Summarize, the solutions is:**

1. Add `tiff_optimizer` as optimization handler:

   ```
   optimizer.AddOptimizationHandler(tiff_optimizer);
   ```
2. Add `System.Drawing.Common` as dependency